# Using HTML Selectors with React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use the `select` tag in React. I have the following component:

```
class InteractionHeader extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            allDays: [],
            selected: ""
        };

        this.dateChanged = this.dateChanged.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            allDays: ["a", "b"],
            selected: "a"
        });
    }

    dateChanged(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.target.value);
    }
}
```

And in my render, I have the following:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <select value={this.state.selected} onChange={this.dateChanged}>
                {this.state.allDays.map((x) => {
                    return <option key={`${x}`} value={`${x}`}>{x}</option>
                })};
            </select>
        </div>
    );
}
```

However, when I select a different option, my console prints `undefined` instead of the option I selected. What is going on and how do I prevent it?

Comment: remove e.preventDefault()

Comment: I added an answer to it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling it wrong

```
dateChanged(e) {
        console.log(e.target.value);
    }
```

You should use prevent default in case where you donot want your page to take a refresh and try to make a server side call. In case of select there is nothing like this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in dateChanged(e) method. You need to log e.target.value instead of event.target.value.